# Monogame texture loading NullReferenceException

Tags: windows-8, xna, monogame

I have a working game where I am loading all the textures from a different class. It works perfectly fine for the PC version.

Now, I am trying to port it to win8 using Monogame.

If I load a texture from Game1.cs using .xnb file it works absolutely fine. However, when I try to load the same texture by using a different class, it doesn't. It gives me an `NullReferenceException` error on

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Cornflowerblue);
```

Comment: Could you check if `GraphicsDevice` is null?

Comment: It is Null! Thats why I have put NullReferenceException

Answer (score 0):

HungryCoder:

I don't know how you are loading the texture from the class, however, right now MonoGame doesn't yet have a Content Pipeline like you were provided with in building and XNA Game for the PC (they are working on it), therefore, you cannot add graphic files in the same manner.

In my walkthrough of building a Windows 8 XNA game, I create my Shooter player graphic from my own Player class by passing into my Initialize function within the class the Content.Load<> with the Texture type and location:

player.Initialize(Content.Load("Graphics\player"), playerPosition);

Note the .xnb file is located in a folder Graphics within my project.

In my background, I have also created a parallaxing background from a my background class by passing in the full Content Manager to my Initialize method of my Background class as well.

bgLayer1 = new ParallaxingBackground();
bgLayer1.Initialize(Content, "Graphics\bgLayer1", GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, -1);

Both of these examples work within my project/game.

If you interested have posted the player code example as a part of blog tutorial series on MonoGame on Windows 8. As I complete the code for the background, I will also add the full code example for the background as well.  Hope this helps. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/tarawalker